# Why Firefox doesn't support Dynamics 365 Operations? Is there any way on Chrome like Firepath in Firefox

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Why Firefox doesn't support Dynamics 365 Operations? 
Is there any way to run Operations on Firefox.

OR
Is there any plugin in Chrome like we have **Firepath** in Firefox.
Because I am facing problem in detecting xpath through Chrome. I tried XPATH Helper also but it is not worth it like Firepath in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain WebUI Controls whose corresponding XML notation does not get rendered properly in Dynamics 365 especially in Firefox.

Its recommended that Google Chrome or Internet Explorer Latest Version should be used until any patch comes for Firefox.